# get internal directory path on galaxy note

Tags: java, android, android-external-storage

In my application I am accessing external storage (it can be part of both internal storage or SD Card according to [this](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesInternal)) by using following method and in my Xperia V it returns the path of internal storage(Not SD card).

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageState().toString();
```

When I tried to run the app on a galaxy note which doesn't have a SD card mounted I found out above method doesn't return the storage path.(app is supposed to save a file if it gets the successful path). So can I know is there a method I can access external storage(which doesn't have an SD card mounted).?

Thank you

Comment: "it returns the path of internal storage" -- no, it returns the path to external storage. Please read the documentation for the definitions of internal and external storage: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#filesExternal

Comment: I did. and it said in some devices part of internal storage has mapped as a external storage (partition from internal storage) which my Xperia V have a external storage mapped from internal storage.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=60398

Comment: Seems like I'm also doing that :/ sorry but I tried to be descriptive as possible. I want to know a method to save my data even if the device don't have a mounted SD card.

Comment: Use `getExternalFilesDir()`, or `getExternalCacheDir()`, or `Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()` (the latter of which is referenced by the one existing answer so far on your question).

Comment: when using `getExternalFilesDir()` and `getExternalCacheDir()` it seems like the file i want to create is not creating because it should have load next time I start the app but it doesn't happen.

Comment: Then you have a bug in your code that you need to fix, apparently. Or, possibly, your device is broken (e.g., flawed ROM installed that is breaking access to external storage). There are hundreds of thousands of Android apps successfully using external storage, and so it is rather unlikely that external storage is broken for all of Android and we somehow just did not notice. Please feel free to ask a new StackOverflow question, where you supply your code that is not working and how you have determined that it is not working.

Answer (score 1):

For getting the external storage path try like this..

```
String root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getPath();
```

It will retun the exact path of external storage

Answer (score 0):

First of all your app must have permission to write external storage, it is specified in manifest file, please see below:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Secondly, we should check if external media is mounted, Please see a working snippet from one of my Android apps it will create a directory for you on external storage if one does not exist already, otherwise return File object for the directory.

```
File getRecordingDirectory()
    {
        File recordingDir = null;

            // get the state of external storage
        String externalStorageState = Environment.getExternalStorageState();

        if(externalStorageState.equals(Environment.MEDIA_MOUNTED))
        {
            File extDir =
                    Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();

            recordingDir = new File(extDir, "AudioRecorder");

            if(!recordingDir.exists())
            {
                if(!recordingDir.mkdirs())
                {
                Log.e("RECORDER", "Unable to create Silent Recorder recordings directory.");
                }
            }
        }
        return recordingDir;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
private String getInternalSDPath() {
    File file = new File("/system/etc/vold.fstab");
    FileReader fr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    try {
        fr = new FileReader(file);
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

    }
    String path = null;
    try {
        if (fr != null) {
            br = new BufferedReader(fr);
            String s = br.readLine();
            while (s != null) {
                if (s.startsWith("dev_mount")) {
                    String[] tokens = s.split("\\s");
                    path = tokens[2]; // mount_point
                    if (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath().equals(path)) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
                s = br.readLine();
            }
        }
    } catch (IOException e) {

    } finally {
        try {
            if (fr != null) {
                fr.close();
            }
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {

        }
    }
    return path;
}
```

To get the external SD card mount directory simply change:

```
                    if (Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath().equals(path)) {
                        break;
                    }
```

To:

```
                    if (!Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()
                            .getAbsolutePath().equals(path)) {
                        break;
                    }
```

**Note:** this method is reather device specific and I can use it because I know I only develop against Samsung devices which have an extra internal storage. If you want this to work for all devices you would have to make a additional changes.